# Bind к существующему экземпляру службы

Tags: android, java

Я запускаю активити, из неё я запускаю службу, затем я закрываю активити но служба работает. Через некоторое время я запускаю туже самую активити и я хочу чтобы эта активити привязалась к той самой ещё работающей службе. Дело в том что привязка к службе у меня прописана в методе onStart() и в итоге , после повторного запуска активити я имею в памяти две службы. Как мне это сделать чтобы привязка происходила к той самой службе, которая была запущена в начале??

Comment: что такое служба? поток или сервис? если сервис - то 2е копии не может быть, если поток - немного сложнее, можно хранить ид, можно проверять его или чтото еще придумать

Comment: в моём случае служба это service. этот service управляет проигрыванием MediaPlayer. необходимо чтобы при запуске второго активити, это активити управляла именно тем MediaPlayer который был запущен первой активити

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет! Не делайте привязку к службе в onStart либо проверяйте каждый раз , привязаны ли Вы уже к ней или  нет .  Стартуйте службу при загрузке устройства (как это сделать - описано в десятках статей) если она Вам так важна  и дальше просто подключайтесь и отключайтесь  когда  нужно ) И когда она больше не нужна - делайте stopSelf в самой службе .  Почитайте вот здесь  если что-то непонятно http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: я не привязываю её методом onStart или onStartCommand. я привзываю её onBind. дело в том что в этой службе проигрывает MediaPlayer, и если службу отвязать(unBind) то вызовется метод onDestroy() службы. Мне же нужно чтобы я мог подключится к службе с помощью одной активити, далее закрыть эту активи, запустить активити №2 , и управлять этим же самым MediaPlayer с помощью второй активити.

Comment: делайте как я Вам сказал .  И не привязывайте работу Вашей службы к какому то activity если это activity не связано  с управлением  режимом MediaPlayer Нужно управлять MediaPlayer из одного activity  где кнопки  Start , Play , Pause . При этом далее когда Вы в другом activity   Mplayer работает сам по себе . У Вас должно быть только одна activity  и сама служба где Вы можете управлять Mplayer . Если есть желание управлять из любого места  то нужно  другое серьезное решение которое думаю Вам не нужно пока Вы не решите задачу с управлением MPlayer только из одного activity

Comment: а как проверить, привязан ли активити к службе до попытки привязки? мне кажется я бы решил проблему запуском метода bindService(intent, serviceConn, 0); c флагом=0 или флагом=BIND_AUTO_CREATE в зависимости от ситуации.

Comment: у меня нет под рукой сейчас готового решения и кода который я бы здесь привёл Нужно погуглить - есть масса способов чтобы проверить Я в одном из своих проектов делал так -  если MPlayer играет то ничего не делаем  и activity уходит  в background а плейер продолжает играть , если он на паузе и выходим из activity  - то службу выгружаем(передаём в onPause() этой activity интент в службу  что  нужно остановиться и приняв этот интент служба  выполняет  stopSelf  .)  Далее можно стартовать новый аудио или видео трек но службу надо стартовать вновь

Comment: открыл сэмплы которые поставлялись с андроид СДК , увидел программку которая порвала мне шаблон - RandomMusicPlayer.
В этой программе не существует привязки (bind), а абсолютно все приказы отправляются методом startService(), даже когда надо стопнуть песню.

Comment: это тоже нормальный вариант; если тело имеет достаточную производительность то разницы не увидим ну а если проц слабый лучше думаю стартовать один раз и потом управлять либо родными методами либо дополнительными обьявленными в AIDL интерфейсе , и когда нужно остановить )